# How does Xcode 4.6 name @synthesized ivars?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4.6

My professor has explicitly told us several times that in Xcode 4.6 calling:

```
@synthesize suit;
```

is the same as calling:

```
@synthesize suit = _suit;
```

in that Xcode will create an ivar and name it with the underbar naming convention (example `@property suit` will get an ivar named `_suit`)

However, I have been looking at documentation and found this passage in the [Apple Documentation EncapsulatingData](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html)

> Important: If you use @synthesize without specifying an instance variable name, like this:
>   @synthesize firstName;
>   the instance variable will bear the same name as the property.
>   In this example, the instance variable will also be called firstName, without an underscore.

This appears to directly contradict my professor. :(

Here is what I know. In Xcode 4.6 any `@property` declared will get `@synthesize`-ed automatically so you wouldn't even need to call `@synthesize`. If you allow Xcode to auto synthesize it does use the ivar underbar name (`_suit`).  However if you implment custom getters and setters you have to call `@synthesize` explicitly.

My question is this.  When you have a custom getter and setter (as I have) and need to call `@ synthesize` does Xcode use the default underbar naming scheme when you don't specify the name?

For example when I call this:

```
@synthesize suit;
```

Does Xcode name the underlying ivar `suit` or `_suit`?

From my simple tests and reading the docs it appears that `@synthesize suit;` becomes `@synthesize suit = suit` and not `@synthesize suit = _suit` as my professor thinks it does.  I am a total rookie, just wrapping my head around properties and synthesizing so I need your help.

Also, what could I do to test this myself or find the actual answer in the docs? Thanks.

Comment: `sed s/Xcode/the compiler/g`

Comment: Sorry @H2CO3 I am super rookie. I don't know what "sed s/Xcode/the compiler/g" means. I googled it and found that s is the substitution command in sed which would replace Xcode with the? Is that a solution or did I use Xcode too frequently in my question? I couldn't find what compiler/g meant.

Comment: He's saying (I believe) you're referencing Xcode when you should be referencing the compiler. i.e. you say "Xcode will create..." when it should be "the compiler will create...".

Comment: @Joshua Carbonic Acid means say "the compiler" instead of "Xcode" in you question.

Comment: People read my mind, this is über-awesome! ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the official word - *Programming with Objective C*
[Encapsulating Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW1), and perhaps also the source of confusion

> **Most Properties Are Backed by Instance Variables**
>
> Unless you specify otherwise, the synthesized instance variable has the same name as the property, but with an underscore prefix. For a property called firstName, for example, the synthesized instance variable will be called _firstName.

Further down the same page (the part you quoted)...

> **You Can Customize Synthesized Instance Variable Names**
>
> **Important**: If you use `@synthesize` without specifying an instance variable name, like this:
> `@synthesize firstName;`
> the instance variable will bear the same name as the property.
> In this example, the instance variable will also be called `firstName`, without an underscore.

They do almost seem to contradict themselves, but the earlier paragraph is only referring to *autosynthesized* instance variables, while the latter is what happens when you explicitly synthesize.

Autosynthesis is a much newer feature which only came to XCode in version 4.4 with the inclusion of Clang compiler v4. Prior to this there were [endless debates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+underscore+ivar+naming+convention) about the pros and cons of @synthesizing your variables with a leading undersore ([legend had it](http://iosptl.com/posts/leading-underscores/) that this was reserved for Apple's use), a trailing underscore (Google's [objective-C style guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml)) or neither. Since XCode 4.4 this is settled: name all your iVars explicitly with a leading underscore, but better still leave the compiler do it for you.

*update*: I noticed Google has [updated their style guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml?showone=Trailing_vs_Leading_Underscores#Trailing_vs_Leading_Underscores) to fit in with the rest of us...

> *Trailing underscores were once preferred for instance variable names.*
>
> Our style guide used to have a rule saying that instance variables should be named with a trailing underscore, similar to the naming of member variables in C++. This was changed to leading underscores to be consistent with the broader Objective-C community, to better follow Apple's official guidelines, *and to allow for use of new compiler features like automatic instance variable synthesis.* New projects are strongly encouraged to use leading underscores. Existing projects may continue to use trailing underscores in new code to maintain consistency with the rest of their codebase.

Answer (score 1):

You are right (and your professor is not). `@synthesize` creates an ivar with the same name as the property if the variable name is not specified.

```
@synthesize foo;
```

...will create an ivar named `foo`

Comment: Seems like now it is changed, I was a bit surprised when came across this post and read answers

Comment: @Injectios No, this did not (and would not) change. If you use @synthesize without specifying a name, the ivar's name will be identical to the property. What's new is the sythesize-by-default feature where you leave out the `@synthesize` directive and still get a synthesized ivar and accessors. In this case the ivar's name is prefixed with the underline.

Comment: I don't use @synthesize anymore, BUT I have property "varName" and can easy access to _varName